# Add text to first element in class on page load with multiple blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The point is:**
Find by Javascript or JQuery **only first** element which contain "analytics" inside *div* `class=""` and add text to this *analytics* at the beginning. This script must work on page load.

**How does it look like**

```
<div id="block_browsing_1" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_browsing_2" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_instagram_followers_1" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_instagram_followers_1" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>
```

How it should look:

```
<div id="block_browsing_1" class="test analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_browsing_2" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_instagram_followers_1" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_instagram_followers_2" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".analytics")[0].classList.add("test");`?

Comment: `block_instagram_followers_1` is assigned to 2 div blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".analytics")[0].classList.add("test");
```

```html
<div id="block_browsing_1" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_browsing_2" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_instagram_followers_1" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>

<div id="block_instagram_followers_2" class="analytics">
  //content
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, this is best solution for me. Thank you.

Comment: we, stackoverflow community, are happy to help you @HubertFurka

Comment: @HubertFurka Yup, thats the one i commented on the post with, and added an answer as you've said...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS selector `first-of-type`

```
$('.analytics:first-of-type').addClass('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple pure javascript solution:

`document.querySelectorAll(".analytics")[0].classList.add("test");`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentClass = $('.analytics').first().attr('class');
  $('.analytics').first().attr('class', 'test ' + currentClass);
});
```

Where `'test'` is the text that you want to add at the beginning

Answer (score -1):

What happened to google first?

```
jQuery(function($){ // act upon document ready event.
  $('.analytics').first().addClass('test');
});
```